# add authentication info for urllib.request

Tags: python, post, python-requests, urllib, urllib2

I had this query with with the requests library:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
}

data = """
{"target": {
  "ref_type": "branch",
  "type": "pipeline_ref_target",
  "ref_name": "main",
  "selector": {
    "type": "branches",
    "pattern" : "main"
    }
  }
}
"""

response = requests.post('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/name/{567899876}/pipelines/', headers=headers, data=data, auth=(username, password))
print(response.text)
```

Now, I want to do the same thing with the urllib.request or urllib3 preferably. I was trying this:

```
from urllib import request, parse

req =  request.Request('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/name/{4567898758}/pipelines/', method="POST", headers=headers, data=data, auth=(username, password))

resp = request.urlopen(req)
print(resp)
```

but urllib doesn't have an `auth`parameter. I saw other examples online. For eg something like this:

```
auth_handler = url.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='Connect2Field API',
                          uri=urlp,
                          user='*****',
                          passwd='*****')
```

but I am not sure how to merge this with my existing `headers` in order to convert my `request` code to a `urllib.request` code.

Comment: You can use `Authorization: Basic <BASE64 USER:PASS>` in case of http native basic auth.

Comment: how exactly? @tbhaxor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to authenticate using urllib you'll need to use the `base64` library to encode your credentials and adding them as header of your request.

```
from urllib import request, parse
import base64

req =  request.Request('https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/name/{4567898758}/pipelines/', method="POST", headers=headers, data=data)

base64string = base64.b64encode(bytes('{}:{}'.format(username, password), 'ascii'))
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic {}'.format(base64string.decode('utf-8')))

resp = request.urlopen(req)
```

**EDIT:**

Using urllib3 you can do something like this

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
headers = urllib3.make_headers(basic_auth='{}:{}'.format(username, password))
resp = http.urlopen('POST', 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/name/{4567898758}/pipelines/', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: wait, in this case, are you completely ignoring my existing headers? Like content-type: application/json?

Comment: You can easily merge your existing header dict with the output of `make_headers` following the accepted answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-take-union-of-dictionari